# JS charting API with user interaction

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm looking for a javascript charting API that would allow user to dynamically modify value points (through drag'n drop) and then provide some callbacks to get those new values.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/) supports this?

Comment: I only checked the demo page (http://www.highcharts.com/demo) but can't find any that does this

Comment: I think you will have to implement this by yourself. Handlers on mouse over / click are there. Then you have to change the value of the point by watching on the mouseposition.

Comment: Ok, I just hoped there'd be an API out there that would provide it out of the box :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a custom plugin for highcharts that provides dragging of chart points: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/:

```
(function (Highcharts) {        
var addEvent = Highcharts.addEvent, each = Highcharts.each;

/**
 * Filter by dragMin and dragMax
 */
function filterRange(newY, series, XOrY) {
    var options = series.options,
        dragMin = options['dragMin' + XOrY],
        dragMax = options['dragMax' + XOrY];

    if (newY < dragMin) {
        newY = dragMin;
    } else if (newY > dragMax) {
        newY = dragMax;
    }
    return newY;
}

Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {

    var container = chart.container,
        dragPoint,
        dragX,
        dragY,
        dragPlotX,
        dragPlotY;

    chart.redraw(); // kill animation (why was this again?)

    addEvent(container, 'mousedown', function (e) {
        var hoverPoint = chart.hoverPoint,
            options;

        if (hoverPoint) {
            options = hoverPoint.series.options;
            if (options.draggableX) {
                dragPoint = hoverPoint;

                dragX = e.pageX;
                dragPlotX = dragPoint.plotX;
            }

            if (options.draggableY) {
                dragPoint = hoverPoint;

                dragY = e.pageY;
                dragPlotY = dragPoint.plotY + (chart.plotHeight - (dragPoint.yBottom || chart.plotHeight));
            }

            // Disable zooming when dragging
            if (dragPoint) {
                chart.mouseIsDown = false;
            }
        }
    });

    addEvent(container, 'mousemove', function (e) {
        if (dragPoint) {
            var deltaY = dragY - e.pageY,
                deltaX = dragX - e.pageX,
                newPlotX = dragPlotX - deltaX - dragPoint.series.xAxis.minPixelPadding,
                newPlotY = chart.plotHeight - dragPlotY + deltaY,
                newX = dragX === undefined ? dragPoint.x : dragPoint.series.xAxis.translate(newPlotX, true),
                newY = dragY === undefined ? dragPoint.y : dragPoint.series.yAxis.translate(newPlotY, true),
                series = dragPoint.series,
                proceed;

            newX = filterRange(newX, series, 'X');
            newY = filterRange(newY, series, 'Y');

            // Fire the 'drag' event with a default action to move the point.
            dragPoint.firePointEvent(
                'drag', {
                newX: newX,
                newY: newY
            },

            function () {
                proceed = true;
                dragPoint.update([newX, newY], false);
                chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.tooltip.shared ? [dragPoint] : dragPoint);
                if (series.stackKey) {
                    chart.redraw();
                } else {
                    series.redraw();
                }
            });

            // The default handler has not run because of prevented default
            if (!proceed) {
                drop();
            }
        }
    });

    function drop(e) {
        if (dragPoint) {
            if (e) {
                var deltaX = dragX - e.pageX,
                    deltaY = dragY - e.pageY,
                    newPlotX = dragPlotX - deltaX - dragPoint.series.xAxis.minPixelPadding,
                    newPlotY = chart.plotHeight - dragPlotY + deltaY,
                    series = dragPoint.series,
                    newX = dragX === undefined ? dragPoint.x : dragPoint.series.xAxis.translate(newPlotX, true),
                    newY = dragY === undefined ? dragPoint.y : dragPoint.series.yAxis.translate(newPlotY, true);

                newX = filterRange(newX, series, 'X');
                newY = filterRange(newY, series, 'Y');
                dragPoint.update([newX, newY]);
            }                
            dragPoint.firePointEvent('drop');
        }
        dragPoint = dragX = dragY = undefined;
    }
    addEvent(document, 'mouseup', drop);
    addEvent(container, 'mouseleave', drop);
});

/**
 * Extend the column chart tracker by visualizing the tracker object for small points
 */
var colProto = Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype,
    baseDrawTracker = colProto.drawTracker;

colProto.drawTracker = function () {
    var series = this;
    baseDrawTracker.apply(series);
    each(series.points, function (point) {
        point.graphic.attr(point.shapeArgs.height < 3 ? {
            'stroke': 'black',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'dashstyle': 'shortdot'
        } : {
            'stroke-width': series.options.borderWidth,
            'dashstyle': series.options.dashStyle || 'solid'
        });
    });
};
})(Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Awesome Free JavaScript Charts review](http://www.splashnology.com/article/15-awesome-free-javascript-charts/325/) and [another one](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/03/09/50-free-resources-for-charts-and-graphs-solution/)